# Iterate through parameters array and ActiveRecord:Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller which needs to implement bulk update. (However, it needs to set specific values to each object vs the same value for all objects).

Here is the array which the controller will get

```
[
  {
    "task_id": 1,
    "some_property": "value1"
  },
  {
    "task_id": 2,
    "some_property": "value2"
  },
]
```

I need to find all tasks and for each task update the property to a provided value.

The obvious solution is

```
task_ids = params[::_json].map { |task| task[:task_id] }
tasks = Task.where(id: task_ids)

tasks.each do |task| 
  params[::_json].each do |task_from_params| do
    if task.id == task_form_params[:task_id] 
       task.some_property = task_form_params[:some_property]
       task.save!
    end
  end
end
```

The thing which I don't like (big time) is the code where we do N^2 comparisons.

I am pretty sure there should be a better way to do in Rails. I am looking for something more concise which doesn't require N^2 comparisons.

Comment: I like the idea of a temporary table in the database for this.  Not sure there's an ORM to accomplish the same.

Comment: @vol7ron Please, can you elaborate?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (task_id, property, value);` … then PUT/COPY statements to load temp table.  Then `UPDATE tasks SET property = foo.value FROM foo WHERE primary_table.id = foo.task_id AND foo.property = 'specific_property';`  Update for each property name.  Of course, you could issue the `UPDATE` dynamically

Comment: Issuing a query for the number of properties should be quicker than a query for the number of tasks to update.  Unless it's one task with many properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: `ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all`

If you don't care about validations and callbacks then you can simply use:

```
params.each do |param|
  Task.where(id: param.fetch('task_id')).
    update_all(some_property: param.fetch('some_property')
end
```

This will iterate over N items in `params` and issue N `UPDATE`s and no `SELECT`s.

## Option 2: Convert to a hash mapping ID to property

If you *do* care about validations or callbacks then you can convert your input array to a hash first:

```
# Convert params to a hash. Iterate over N items.
id_to_property = params.map do |param|
  [param.fetch('task_id'), param.fetch('some_property')]
end.to_h

# Load corresponding tasks. Iterate over N keys.
Task.where(id: id_to_property.keys).find_each do |task|
  # Look up the property value - O(1).
  task.update!(some_property: id_to_property[task.id])
end
```

Comment: I like option 2. I think option 1 will end up with N+1 queries problem (https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html)

Comment: Are you also updating the associations? If not, then N+1 wont occur. Option 1 will actually issue less queries than option 2 as it won't run any `SELECT`s.

Comment: Oh... This is interesting. I was under impression that option 1 will do select first and after it will do update. However, if it doesn't do select then it's actually better